# Why does this VOR's compass has an arrow pointing north east?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, vor

[The VOR compass here](https://skyvector.com/?ll=19.282488889,166.636661111&chart=301&zoom=1) has an arrow that points to the north east. I never saw an VOR compass like that. What is the explanation?

Comment: Wrong tab there

Comment: Everything points to Ozzy Osbourne...

Comment: ***Every*** VOR compass has a declination one direction or another.  If you've never seen that before, its only because you never looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ICAO SARPS Annex 4:

[image]

This is due to the [magnetic declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination), which varies from place to place, as well as over time.

Note that VOR stations are typically not realigned over time, so discrepancies may arise with respect to the ever changing magnetic north, but in radio navigation a radial is just that – drawn over a chart, and tuned to, it will always be the same.

Further reading:

- http://www.magnetic-declination.com/what-is-magnetic-declination.php

Comment: So the arrow points to magnetic north?

Comment: @TomMcW: Not always, see update.

Comment: This answer could be improved by clarifying that the "arrow" in the figure in the original question points to some version of "north", more specifically to some version of magnetic north, which due to various reasons might not be exactly the same as the actual magnetic north but it's pretty close.  I don't think the originally asker had any idea that the arrow was a north-pointing index of any kind at all.