# Why does the 0 radial on a sectional's VOR appear not to point to magnetic north?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, vor, magnetic-variation

I have been scanning sectional charts and have noticed that the local magnetic declination is always a few degrees off from the 0 radial of VOR's around it. I have been told that the two are supposed to be the same. See image below from skyvector as an example. In this image, the local magnetic declination is 14.5 degree east. The OED VOR however has its 0 radial pointing roughly 19 degrees east of true north (which can be seen from the adjoining longitude line).

[image]

This is one example, but I see similar discrepancies all over the U.S. I have read in many places that VOR's 0 radials point to magnetic north but I have not seen many actual cases on sectionals. What gives? Possible reasons:

1. They do point to magnetic north. But something about the sectional is causing the apparent discrepancy
2. They don't point to magnetic north but they did at some point. Since magnetic declination changes over time, the VOR's 0 radial was truly pointing at magnetic north in the past but is no longer.
3. They don't point to magnetic north for another reason.

If VOR's aren't truly aligned to magnetic north, then it seems that going outbound on radial 090 from a VOR will not necessarily mean you are going magnetic east. And I have read on online articles and other sources that it is useful to use VOR compass roses when plotting magnetic courses. This would appear to cause errors of 5 degrees or so which seems significant.

Comment: We have a couple of questions that might help: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64939/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49507/62)

Comment: Thank you, the second link answers my question (it's #2 on my list) and even educates me on the difference between magnetic declination and magnetic variation! Not sure how to consider my question answered at this point.